# framework opencv2 missing module

Tags: swift, xcode, opencv, frameworks

I created `foo.framework` including `opencv2.framework` with `Embed Without Signing` option.

I can't used `foo.framework` in other project, because `opencv2 missing module` error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0GOB.png)

`opencv2.framework` is included `module` folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G56bL.png)

but `foo.framework` inside `opencv2.framework` is excluded `module`

how can i included `module` folder?

manually copied `opencv2.framework` folder in `foo.framework` it's work!

but i want to creating framework to copy `opencv2.framework`

Answer (score 0):

To include the opencv2.framework module folder within the foo.framework, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Xcode and navigate to the project that contains the foo.framework target.
2. Select the foo.framework target and go to the "Build Phases" tab.
3. Expand the "Embed Frameworks" section.
4. Click on the "+" button to add a new framework.
5. In the file chooser dialog, navigate to the location where the opencv2.framework is located.
6. Select the opencv2.framework and click on the "Add" button.

This should add the opencv2.framework as an embedded framework within the foo.framework. Now, when you use the foo.framework in other projects, the opencv2 module should be included along with it.

Note: Make sure that the opencv2.framework is properly linked and included as a dependency in the project that creates the foo.framework. Also, ensure that you have the correct version of opencv2.framework that includes the required module.